# How can I auto accept cookies pop windows Automation Java

Tags: java, angular, selenium, automation

What is the wrong in my code , why auto click doesn't work in accept cookies button. This website using angular application.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import com.paulhammant.ngwebdriver.ByAngular;
import com.paulhammant.ngwebdriver.NgWebDriver;

public class NewClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\Hp\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    NgWebDriver ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
                    ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
        driver.get("https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/deu/login/");
        ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
        ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();           
        driver.findElement(ByAngular.options("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")).click();
 }

}
```

Attached Image here [image: Just want to auto click this pop up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use this line

```
driver.findElement(ByAngular.options("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")).click();
```

it will try to find the element immediately, often resulting in errors. Cause web element/elements have not been rendered properly.

This is main reason we should opt for [Explicit waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait), implemented by WebDriverWait.

> They allow your code to halt program execution, or freeze the thread,
> until the condition you pass it resolves. The condition is called with
> a certain frequency until the timeout of the wait is elapsed. This
> means that for as long as the condition returns a falsy value, it will
> keep trying and waiting.

**Code :**

```
Webdriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

As per my knowledge there is no way to auto accept cookies using `ChromeOptions` you need to find the element and click.

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/deu/login/");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add wait functionality before entering username and password,

if pop up interrupt while entering, username and password will not be proper.

In my case, i created a common method wait and click,

```
   dh.wait_for_the_element_then_do(By.xpath("//button[text()='Accept All Cookies']"), "click", "", "cookies popo up");
   dh.wait_for_the_element_then_do(By.xpath("//input[@tcp-auto='input-username']"),"send", username, "login username");
   dh.wait_for_the_element_then_do(By.xpath("//input[@tcp-auto='input-password']"),"send", password, "login password");
   dh.wait_for_the_element_then_do(By.xpath("//span[text()='Sign in']"),"click", "", "signin button");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution of my problem.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import com.paulhammant.ngwebdriver.ByAngular;
import com.paulhammant.ngwebdriver.NgWebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

public class NewClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\Hp\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    NgWebDriver ngWebDriver = new NgWebDriver(driver);
                    ngWebDriver.waitForAngularRequestsToFinish();
        driver.get("https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/deu/login");
                    driver.manage().window().maximize();
                    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
                    
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
           .elementToBeClickable(By.id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")))
           .click();
```